# PayPal infinite billing plan - how to create?

Tags: paypal, billing

I am trying to create an infinite billing plan with the PayPal API, but I am unsure how to create this.

If I try to set total_cycles to 0 the API rejects this as invalid input with the response that total_cycles must be between 1-999.

Using total_cycles: 999 as a value returns this as invalid input with the response that total_cycles must be between 1-999!

Using total_cycles: 998 is accepted! Grr!

There appears to be an "off by 1" error in the API at the very least.

So: How does one create an infinite subscription?  I don't want subscriptions to end after 998 occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

According to their own [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definitions), `0` is the correct value.

> The number of times this billing cycle runs. Trial billing can only
>   have maximum value of 1 for total_cycles. **In case of infinite regular
>   billing cycle, total_cycles can be set to 0**. For finite regular
>   billing cycle, total_cycles can be set between 1 and 999. Default: 1.
>
> Minimum value: 0.
>
> Maximum value: 999.

Sounds like a bug. You should report an issue if it's still a problem: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues

**Update**

I just tried it with `0` in their sandbox environment and it appears to have worked.